# LightSwitch - Conditional formatting of data in a row / cell

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a list and details screen whereby I want to show certain rows in italics in the list if they pass a certain condition. Ie: priority < 10 from a field on the datasource that is not displayed on the screen.

This does not seem possible through the out of the box controls; would I have to create my own custom silverlight gridview control to accomplish this? If so, any tips on the simplest way??

Currently the formatting is hard coded as bold for all rows using a constantexpression as shown below.

```
<ControlPropertySource Property="Microsoft.LightSwitch:RootControl/Properties[FontStyle]">
 <ScreenExpressionTree>
  <ChainExpression>                                                
   <ConstantExpression ResultType=":String"
                       Value="Strong" />
  </ChainExpression>
 </ScreenExpressionTree>
</ControlPropertySource>
```

Comment: you can do a custom control; or you could try `FindControl` and edit the control's properties.